# Error in MainPage in Silverlight Application

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-5.0

> I am very new to the Silver Light application. When I tried to create one silverlight application, I am getting an error in mainpage designer

```
    System.NullReferenceException
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.Windows.Design.Platform.SilverlightMetadataContext.SilverlightXamlExtensionImplementations.<GetXmlNamespaceCompatibilityMappings>d__8.MoveNext()
   at MS.Internal.Design.Metadata.ReflectionProjectNode.BuildSubsumption()
   at MS.Internal.Design.Metadata.ReflectionProjectNode.SubsumingNamespace(Identifier identifier)
   at MS.Internal.Design.Markup.XmlElement.BuildScope(PrefixScope parentScope, IParseContext context)
   at MS.Internal.Design.Markup.XmlElement.ConvertToXaml(XamlElement parent, PrefixScope parentScope, IParseContext context, IMarkupSourceProvider provider)
   at MS.Internal.Design.DocumentModel.DocumentTrees.Markup.XamlSourceDocument.FullParse(Boolean convertToXamlWithErrors)
   at MS.Internal.Design.DocumentModel.DocumentTrees.Markup.XamlSourceDocument.get_RootItem()
   at Microsoft.Windows.Design.DocumentModel.Trees.ModifiableDocumentTree.get_ModifiableRootItem()
   at Microsoft.Windows.Design.DocumentModel.MarkupDocumentManagerBase.get_LoadState()
   at MS.Internal.Host.PersistenceSubsystem.Load()
   at MS.Internal.Host.Designer.Load()
   at MS.Internal.Designer.VSDesigner.Load()
   at MS.Internal.Designer.VSIsolatedDesigner.VSIsolatedView.Load()
   at MS.Internal.Designer.VSIsolatedDesigner.VSIsolatedDesignerFactory.Load(IsolatedView view)
   at MS.Internal.Host.Isolation.IsolatedDesigner.BootstrapProxy.LoadDesigner(IsolatedDesignerFactory factory, IsolatedView view)
   at MS.Internal.Host.Isolation.IsolatedDesigner.BootstrapProxy.LoadDesigner(IsolatedDesignerFactory factory, IsolatedView view)
   at MS.Internal.Host.Isolation.IsolatedDesigner.Load()
   at MS.Internal.Designer.DesignerPane.LoadDesignerView()
```

Can any one can provide me a solution for this. Am using Silverlight 5, VS 2010, .Net Framework 4

Answer (score 0):

Consult this page:

[New MS Update causes VS2010 Silverlight project to have error in Design WPF editor](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/718259/new-ms-update-causes-vs2010-silverlight-project-to-have-error-in-design-wpf-editor)

Answer (score 0):

> Dear All
>
> > I found the solution after spending hours in installing and uninstalling different versions >>of silverlight.

```
Follow the Steps for the solution

Step1: Uninstall all the things related to Silverlight
Step2: Install the Silverlight4.0
Step3: Install Silverlight3 SDK
```

> > Now Open the project , There may be chance to Browsers ask for latest Silverlight version. >>But ignore this.

Comment: I wonder if you have found it by looking at the article I have suggested... Just saying...